# GWT/Maven/Eclipse - Development Mode: URL not showing in Eclipse (only JavaEE version!)

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, gwt, maven

I followed instructions on how to setup a maven gwt project using the gwt-maven-plugin. It works nicely, and under a 64-bit version of eclipse downloaded for Windows, with Java packages added later via EPP update sites, it works beautifully. However, on my mac, with eclipse downloaded directly from website as a pre-built, JavaEE bundle, the URL never shows in Development Mode (though I can still launch with maven gwt:compile gwt:run) and I get the following warning message in the eclipse console:

```
Loading modules
   com.dharma.greg.Home
      Validating <servlet> tags for module 'com.dharma.greg.Home'
         [WARN] Module declares a servlet class 'com.dharma.greg.server.ServicesImpl', but the web.xml has no corresponding declaration; please add the following lines to your web.xml:
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servicesImpl</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.dharma.greg.server.ServicesImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>servicesImpl</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/com.dharma.greg.Home/services</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: 
http://blog.slackers.se/2010/01/no-url-showing-in-gwt-20-development.html

Comment: Where should that configuration go?